# Errors trying to link a form from a different project to my main form of another project in same solution in VB. NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to see if I was able to link a menu item (For sake of examples: DisplayProject) in my main Form1 to a Form1 in another project (Project name: PopUpMessage) that is in the same solution.

I already added it from the reference option, so I am able to use the object in my main Form1.

I thought maybe by declaring the following it would work within this menuitem from MenuStrip. I wrapped this in a "try/catch" by the way which is why I get that pop up windows:

```
        Try
           PopUpMessage.Form1.ActiveForm.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

I am declaring this in DisplayMessage project Form1 menustrip item. However I get the error:

[error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1S8c.png)

As daring as I am, I decided  to do the following:

```
    Try
       PopUpMessage.Form1.ActiveForm.Visible = False
       PopUpMessage.Form1.ActiveForm.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Then I go the following error: 
[Second Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcQnm.png)

Anyone has an idea what can be done? I'm kinda new to this type of methods used in VB .NET.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Also what is `PopUpMessage`, put a break point on that line, debug and when it stops hover your mouse over the object, what is it?

Comment: well, my issue isn't entirely focused on that error. It just so happens to appear after I add a line after the first error. 

PopUpMessage is the name of the project as I used it as an example to what I am trying to do.  There are two projects called DisplayMessage and PopUpMessage in 1 solution. PopUpMessage has Form1 and I wanr to access it from DisplayMessage project so that it may appear when I click the menu item in Form1 of project DisplayMessage

Answer (score 1):

Already found the way to do it. For future reference it's:

```
Dim PopUpMessage As New PopUpMessage.Form1
    Try
        PopUpMessage.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

That was all...

Answer (score 0):

You've found the right answer, but to explain what you saw:
`Form.ActiveForm` is a `Shared` `Property` and returns the current foreground form, if there is one, not specific to your `Class`.

Then, either `ShowDialog` correctly complains you're trying to redisplay an already visible form or you're trying to execute a method on `Nothing`.